Grafana pivot table
I have three SQL Server tables built like this:

SAMPLES (id, sample_number, sample_date, description)
PARAMETERS (id, parameter_name, measure_unit)
RESULTS (id, sample_id FK, parameter_id FK, value)

I need to show a table in Grafana obtained by a join on this three tables and group them by description first and then by date. I have it in Excel and I need to obtain the same on Grafana. The Excel looks like this:

I tried with this query:
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT 
    @cols = STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(parameter_name), ', ')  
FROM 
    PARAMETERS;

SET @query = '
SELECT 
    description AS "Description",
    sample_date AS "Date", ' + @cols + '
FROM 
    (SELECT S.description, S.sample_date, P.parameter_name, R.value
     FROM SAMPLES S
     JOIN RESULTS R ON S.id = R.sample_id
     JOIN PARAMETERS P ON R.parameter_id = P.id) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
    (MAX(value) 
     FOR parameter_name IN (' + @cols + ')
    ) AS PivotTable
ORDER BY 
    description, sample_date;';

EXEC sp_executesql @query;

But I do not obtain what I need and I don't have any Idea on how I can modify the query to do that or how to configure Grafana Transformations correctly.
Thanks

Some testdata in table format would help your question get some more traction. But anyway, sql server cannot do this nested column headers easy, so you might not be able to achieve exactly what you want

If you want to transform the data in Grafana, why are you using a dynamic pivot in T-SQL? Surely it would be better to return a normalised data set, and Grafana does the pivoting?

@ThomA I just wanted to show what I tried, I don't know what is the best way to obtain that...in fact, I don't know any way =( . Can you please give me a more detailed description of what would you do? Thank you

I, unfortunately, have no experience with Grafana, however, after I read the tag description that prompted my question. Doing the dynamic pivoting in the SQL layer is rarely the correct place, and it's often much better done in the presentation layer that has better™ tools available to do such transformations.

In SQL you would have to include the Group in the column name like D1 12/06/24, D1 19/06/24, ..., D2 12/06/24, ...

@OlivierJacot-Descombes do you mean that I have to create a new column for each couple description-date? If you mean something else, can you please explain better? I don't understand...

No, what I mean is that you have to concatenate the texts to make one value like Description + ' ' + Date AS ColumnName and pivot on it.

To expand on OlivierJacot-Descombes's comments, this db<>fiddle demonstrates this approach. This is the best you are going to get from a SQL pivot, which only supports single level column labels. You may still need to rebuild the headers in your presentation layer (grafana). As others have suggested, it is probably better to investigate performing the pivot in the presentation layer, where you may have greater control over the column layout and labeling.
